# Examples of analytic $\mathcal{I}$-mad families

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

If $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal (proper and containing the finite sets) on $\omega$, call a family of subsets $\mathcal{A}\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ *$\mathcal{I}$-almost disjoint* if for all distinct $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$, $A\cap B\in\mathcal{I}$. Such a family is *$\mathcal{I}$-mad* if it is maximal with respect to this property.

A well-known theorem of Mathias says that, for $\mathcal{I}=[\omega]^{<\omega}$, there are no infinite analytic $\mathcal{I}$-mad families. At the extreme opposite end of the spectrum, if $$\mathcal{I}=\left\{A\subseteq\omega:\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap n|}{n}=0\right\},$$ the densitiy zero ideal, then there are countably infinite (and thus analytic) $\mathcal{I}$-mad families.

My question: Are there examples of analytic ideals $\mathcal{I}$ for which there are no countable $\mathcal{I}$-mad families, but there are *analytic* $\mathcal{I}$-mad families? If $\mathcal{I}$ is a $P$-ideal, I gather that a result of Farah requires $\mathcal{I}$ to be $F_\sigma$ for the former clause to occur.